# Liferay JSF theme display issue

Tags: jsf-2, liferay, liferay-theme

Am newbie to Liferay and i have created the JSF plugin project. Liferay and Liferay SDK version is 7 i have using. I got issue when am deploying and running service. I have configured with with following ivy.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ivy-module
version="2.0"
xmlns:m2="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
>
<info module="portlet_primefaces_tmpl" organisation="com.liferay">
    <extends extendType="configurations,description,info" location="../../ivy.xml" module="com.liferay.sdk" organisation="com.liferay" revision="latest.integration" />
</info>

<dependencies defaultconf="default">
    <dependency name="jboss-el" org="org.jboss.el" rev="2.0.1.GA" />
    <dependency name="jsf-api" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.2.5" />
    <dependency name="jsf-impl" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.2.5" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-api" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="4.2.5-ga6" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-impl" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="4.2.5-ga6" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-portal" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="4.2.5-ga6" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-util" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="4.2.5-ga6" />
    <dependency name="org.primefaces.primefaces" org="com.liferay" rev="3.5" />
    <dependency conf="test->default" name="arquillian-junit-container" org="org.jboss.arquillian.junit" rev="1.1.6.Final" />
    <dependency conf="test->default" name="arquillian-tomcat-remote-7" org="org.jboss.arquillian.container" rev="1.0.0.CR6" />
    <dependency conf="test->default" name="com.liferay.ant.arquillian" org="com.liferay" rev="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
</dependencies>
```

When running the service i got the exception as follows

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay cannot be found by jsfneon-portlet_7.0.0.1
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:394)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:349)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.context.internal.BridgePortalContextLiferayCompatImpl.isLiferayNamingspacingParameters(BridgePortalContextLiferayCompatImpl.java:47)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.context.internal.BridgePortalContextLiferayImpl.<init>(BridgePortalContextLiferayImpl.java:92)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.filter.internal.BridgePortletRequestFactoryImpl.getRenderRequest(BridgePortletRequestFactoryImpl.java:82)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.internal.BridgePhaseRenderImpl.<init>(BridgePhaseRenderImpl.java:77)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.internal.BridgePhaseFactoryImpl.getBridgeRenderPhase(BridgePhaseFactoryImpl.java:52)
at com.liferay.faces.bridge.internal.BridgeImpl.doFacesRequest(BridgeImpl.java:133)
at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doView(GenericFacesPortlet.java:258)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:359)
at javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet.doDispatch(GenericFacesPortlet.java:207)
at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:262)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:103)
at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:57)
at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:105)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletExceptionAdapter.service(ServletExceptionAdapter.java:68)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:50)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.FilterExceptionAdapter.doFilter(FilterExceptionAdapter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.FilterRegistration.doFilter(FilterRegistration.java:121)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:45)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:70)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:117)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:529)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:604)
at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:391)
at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.render(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:261)
at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1549)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:64)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:671)
at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:145)
at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:155)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:126)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.render(PortletRenderer.java:73)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doProcessTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:444)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doDispatch(RuntimePageImpl.java:286)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:113)
at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:125)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePageUtil.java:70)
at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:747)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectServletPathRegisterDispatcher.include(DirectServletPathRegisterDispatcher.java:67)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
at com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutTypeControllerImpl.includeLayoutContent(LayoutTypeControllerImpl.java:168)
at com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutImpl.includeLayoutContent(LayoutImpl.java:869)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:339)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.doExecute(LayoutAction.java:178)
at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:75)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:170)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:568)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:545)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:180)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.init.servlet.filter.internal.InitFilter.processFilter(InitFilter.java:52)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:93)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:303)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:172)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:180)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:93)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:336)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:303)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:269)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter.processFilter(CacheFilter.java:422)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:86)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:268)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:358)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:65)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have stuck with this problem. And i had no idea to overcome this. I got this issue only when using as plugin project. When am using Liferay JSF project it's working fine.

Comment: have you used service buider in your plugin project?

Comment: Yes. I have used in my project and configured based on liferay tutorial

Comment: can you post the link of this tutorial? also, take a look here: https://web.liferay.com/pt/web/neil.griffin/blog/-/blogs/liferay-faces-project-news-april-2016

Comment: Thanks Marcelo. Here is the link i have referred for service builder configuration. https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-service-builder-to-generate-a-persistence-fr

Comment: you said you are using Liferay JDK 7, but this tutorial you posted is for liferay 6.2.... if possible, try to find and follow a tutorial specific for your JDK version for example this one: https://dev.liferay.com/pt/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/generating-a-jsf-application

Comment: Bezerra. Thanks for the link. Now i can able to generate the JSF. But not able to create the service builder for generated applications. Is there any article available for creating JSF application with liferay 7

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong versions of the Liferay Faces jars. https://liferayfaces.org shows the correct versions that should be used. I have edited Ivy.xml with another dependency configuration. And deleted the list of jars which is generated when deployed the JSF portlet in lib folder. And i have replaced the following jars into my lib (WEB-INF) folder.

> 1. com.liferay.faces.bridge.api-4.0.0.jar
> 2. com.liferay.faces.bridge.ext-5.0.0.jar
> 3. com.liferay.faces.bridge.impl-4.0.0.jar
> 4. com.liferay.faces.util-3.0.0.jar
> 5. commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
> 6. commons-io-2.4.jar
> 7. javax.faces-2.2.13.jar
> 8. javax.faces-api-2.2.jar
> 9. jboss-el-2.0.1.GA.jar

Ivy.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ivy-module
version="2.0"
xmlns:m2="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
>
<info module="portlet_jsf_tmpl" organisation="com.liferay">
    <extends extendType="configurations,description,info" location="../../ivy.xml" module="com.liferay.sdk" organisation="com.liferay" revision="latest.integration" />
</info>

<dependencies defaultconf="default">
    <dependency name="jboss-el" org="org.jboss.el" rev="2.0.1.GA" />
    <dependency name="com.liferay.faces.bridge.impl" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="4.0.0" />
    <dependency name="com.liferay.faces.bridge.ext" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="5.0.0" />
    <dependency name="javax.faces-api" org="javax.faces" rev="2.2" />
    <dependency name="javax.faces" org="org.glassfish" rev="2.2.13" />
    <dependency name="liferay-faces-portal" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
    <dependency conf="test->default" name="arquillian-junit-container" org="org.jboss.arquillian.junit" rev="1.1.6.Final" />
    <dependency conf="test->default" name="arquillian-tomcat-remote-7" org="org.jboss.arquillian.container" rev="1.0.0.CR6" />
    <dependency conf="test->default" name="com.liferay.ant.arquillian" org="com.liferay" rev="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
</dependencies>
```

Now i can able to deploy and view the JSF portlet in portal.